# Importing SS_cons from stockholm (Rfam) alignment using Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

Does anybody know how to recover the SS_cons from a multiple alignment (stockholm, Rfam) with Biopython? The file is read in as a AlignIO object. I'm importing a multiple alignment (1990 sequences) with the following format:

```
BAAY01001440.1/1679-1604                   ....................GG.CU.G.U.G.AC.G.C.AA.AGC.U..A
BABD01024787.1/545-457                     ....................CA.UA.A.G.G.UC.G.C.AA.AGC.C..A
AAUQ01092265.1/84-10                       ....................GG.CG.G.G.G.AC.G.G.AA.AGC.C..A
#=GC SS_cons                               ....................>>.>>.>.>......>.>....<<<.<...
#=GC RF                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.gg.cg.g.g.G.AC.G.C.AA.AgC.c..A
```

I've tried:

```
record.letter_annotations('secondary_structure')
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: '_RestrictedDict' object is not callable
```

It could be that call is only available when there is a secondary structure for each sequence, which is not the case here. Regardless, I figure there should be away to recover the SS_cons. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use this, square brackets as in a typical Python dictionary:

```
record.letter_annotations['secondary_structure']
```

Python uses round brackets for function or method arguments (or in the terminology of Python, callables) and this isn't a function or method (which is what that Python exception is trying to tell you).

However, that won't give you what you want which is a property of the alignment as a whole, not any individual record - see https://redmine.open-bio.org/issues/3387